# Swapping USB3 lines

Tags: pcb, usb, pcb-design

Can the positive and negative line of USB3 SS connections be swapped?

I ask this, as I have seen that it was done in the schematic of the Cypress FX3. Or is this an error in the schematic representation?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

According to AN70707 Page 16:

> The  polarity  can  be  swapped  on  the  USB  3.0  differential  pairs.  Polarity  detection  is  done  automatically  by  the USB 3.0 PHY during link training, as define in the USB3.0 specification section 6.4.2, and does not require any additional  changes  to  device  Firmware.  Given  the  different  USB  connectors  pin-out,  the  polarity  inversion 
>   mechanism can be utilized to ensure that USB traces do not cross each other.

Comment: What does "the polarity inversion mechanism can be utilized to ensure that USB traces do not cross each other" mean?

Comment: USB 3.0 standard  does have the "polarity inversion mechanism" implemented in hardware. "Can be utilized" means that you better route the trace pair in best way to keep signal integrity rather than twisting them to meet + and - polarity.